# How to find time interval between two dates that are in year and week format eg. 201630 and 201951 in r

Tags: r

How to find the interval between two dates that are in year and week format. Example 201630 and 201851

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @thelatemail pointed out if you have week number you also need day of the week to get the date. We can use `%U` to identify week number and `%u` to get day of the week. We use an arbitrary day of the week (here 1).

```
d1 <- as.character(201630)
d2 <- as.character(201851)

diff(as.Date(paste0(c(d1,d2),"1"), format="%Y%U%u"))
#Time difference of 882 days
```

Of if you need output in another unit we can also use `difftime`

```
difftime(as.Date(paste0(d2, 1), "%Y%U%u"), 
         as.Date(paste0(d1, 1), "%Y%U%u"), units = "weeks")
```

Comment: I'd check the output of those `as.Date()` calls. I don't think they're right because those source dates aren't exactly 2 years apart.

Comment: Stealing from the potential duplicate, I think you need something like `diff(as.Date(paste0(c(d1,d2),"1"), format="%Y%U%u"))`

Comment: @thelatemail ahh okay..so it also needs day of the week to correctly get the date when using week number. Makes sense.I'll update.

Comment: @YashodaSingh which code are you using? Can you also share `dput(head(df))` where `df` is your dataframe name so that it is easy to reproduce your issue?

Comment: Hey @RonakShah I am trying to mutate a column where I can have the difference of Original date and returning date that are in year and week format. I tried mutating columns and used your codes but failed.          test <- as.character(Customer_Retention_a$ORIGINAL_WEEK)
test1 <- as.character(Customer_Retention_a$RETURNING_WEEK)
A <- difftime(as.Date(paste0(test1, 1), "%Y%U%u"), 
         as.Date(paste0(test, 1), "%Y%U%u"), units = "days")

Comment: @Yashoda Singh what is `class(Customer_Retention_a$ORIGINAL_WEEK)` ? If it's of date class you don't need to add `paste` to it. You need to do it only for columns with year week format. Try doing `A <- difftime(as.Date(paste0(Customer_Retention_a$RETURNING_WEEK,1), "%Y%U%u"), Customer_Retention_a$ORIGINAL_WEEK)` also try `A <- difftime(as.Date(paste0(Customer_Retention_a$RETURNING_WEEK,1), "%Y%U%u"), as.Date(Customer_Retention_a$ORIGINAL_WEEK))` if it's of class character.